# PHP PDO Query to DB2 returns NULL on CLI but data through APACHE

Tags: php, pdo, db2

I am making a connection to a DB2 instance via PHP -> PDO -> ODBC and running a super simple query:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT COL2, HEX(COL2) from DB.TABLE WHERE COL1 = '12345'";
$connDb2 = new PDO("odbc:DSN=aDsn;Userid=User;Password=aPassword");
$statement = $connDb2->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

When running from CLI, if the result has any unicode characters in it, I get a NULL result back from PDO (though the hex translation of the result is fine):

```
array(2) {
  ["COL2"]=>
  NULL
  ["00002"]=>
string(60) "D1C1D5C5D3D3C540D4C1D5E2E2E2E2414040404040404040404040404040"
}
```

However, if I run the same script through Apache, I get a non-null result:

```
array(2) {
["COL2"]=>
string(30) "JANELLE MANSSSS� "
["00002"]=>
string(60) "D1C1D5C5D3D3C540D4C1D5E2E2E2E2414040404040404040404040404040"
}
```

If there are no unicode characters, the results are the same via CLI or Apache.  Help!?!?!?!

Comment: Which operating-system runs PHP?  Which locale is active for the session that runs PHP and how do you verify this?

Comment: There's different php.ini files for CLI and web. Look for differences there.

Comment: I am running this under PHP 7.2.33 / Apache 2.4.43 on an Amazon Linux 2 server.  With this configuration, there is only a single php.ini under /etc.

Comment: And when you run it thought CLI, does the same user run the executable then when Apache does it? Might otherwise change the locale.